# Can I display an image created with PHP/GD without saving and without using external PHP with image header?

Tags: php, image, gd

I'm trying to create a way to show an image created with PHP/GD, in an OOP fashion. In order to accomplish that, I created a class that, among other things, creates an image. Something like this:

```
<?php
    class MyClass 
    {
        public $image;
        function __construct()
        {
           ...
           $this->image = imagecreatetruecolor(100,100);
           $bg = imagecolorallocate($this->image,100,100,100);
           imagefilledrectangle($this->image,0,0,100,100,$bg);
           ...
        }
        ...
    }

    $myvar = new MyClass
?>
```

I tried to create a function within the class that would output the image. Something like this:

```
function show()
{
    echo "<img src='" . imagejpeg($this->image,100) . "' />";
}
```

but it didn't work. I also tried

```
function show()
{
    echo "<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64," . imagejpeg($this->image,100) . "' />";
}
```

but this also didn't work. The idea was to simply call the function from the HTML. Like this:

```
<div id='anyid'>
    <?php $myvar->show(); ?>
</div>
```

Am I going all wrong on this? Is there a way to accomplish what I want? I tried to think of a way to use the **img='mycode.php'** but it doesn't work for me because the class has to be created before the page loads and the image appears half way through the page.

Thanks.

Comment: You almost had it with show() - you just need to base64_encode the output

Answer (score 35, accepted):

First, you need to insert a second parameter to `imagejpeg()` to allow `100` to be the quality parameter. Then, you need to **base64-encode the raw bytes**:

```
    public function show() {

        // Begin capturing the byte stream
        ob_start();

        // generate the byte stream
        imagejpeg($this->image, NULL, 100);

        // and finally retrieve the byte stream
        $rawImageBytes = ob_get_clean();

        echo "<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64," . base64_encode( $rawImageBytes ) . "' />";

    }
```

The `data:image/jpeg;base64` requires the **raw bytes to get encoded as base64**.

Additionally, I'd propose to make `$image` a `protected` variable, since I suppose it is created and maintained solely inside of `MyClass`.

Comment: Thanks SteAp. I tried, but when I look at the html code, what I get is **<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,MQ==' />**

Comment: The imagejpeg() function will have to be wrapped with output buffering functions to capture the content, you may find a file called "100" that has your image in your website folder, imagejpeg() can only echo or write to file, not return :)

Comment: @Scuzzy My fault. Pass NULL as second parameter to allow 100 to be the third parameter.

Comment: ob_start();imagejpeg($this->image,null,100);$rawImageBytes = ob_get_clean();

Comment: @Scuzzy Absolutely. Your are right, Scuzzy! Thx! Nevertheless, passing NULL as second parameter is essential too.

Comment: It worked beautifully. Thank you very much. Tested on FF9, IE9 and Chrome16. All perfect.

Comment: @setnara erdnaxela You are welcome! Have fun coding! Don't forget to accept the answer - or people might stop answering ;-)

Comment: For those who want to understand what ob_ functions does check this link [http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php). Basically, control output and capture all php outputs between ob_start and end to a internal var.

Comment: this is not working on IE6, IE7 `http://caniuse.com/#search=Data%20URIs`

Answer (score 1):

One single code line, solve-me after 3 hours of blind search!

```
...
ob_start();
header( "Content-type: image/jpeg" ); <br/>
imagejpeg( $this->img, NULL, $qualidade );<br/>
imagedestroy( $this->img );<br/>
$i = ob_get_clean();<br/>

echo "<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64," . base64_encode( $i )."'>";   //saviour line!
```

thks!